# Update a MongoDB Document (in NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a user document

```
username: "Ralph",
email: "ralph@gmail.com",
resetPasswordToken: null,
resetPasswordExpires: null
```

and **I want to update the resetPasswordToken and the resetPasswordExpires** properties in an Express route,

I did this :

```
router.post("/forgotPassword", (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then(user => {
    if (user === null) {
      console.log("NO user with this mail exists");
    } else {
      console.log("user with this mail exists");

      const token = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString("hex");
      const myDate = new Date();
      const newDate = new Date(myDate);

      user.update({
        resetPasswordToken: token,
        resetPasswordExpires: newDate.setHours(newDate.getHours() + 1)
      });
```

I see the log "user with this mail exists" in the terminal, but the user.update is never done, because there are no changes in my MongoDB database,

Does someone have a solution ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> FYI: .update() is deprecated by Mongo. You should switch to .updateOne()

On that note, you need to call the .updateOne() function on your model, not on the returned promise.

```
router.post("/forgotPassword", (req, res) => {
    // deconstruct email from form 
    const { email } = req.body

    // check if email is registered in the database
    User.findOne({ email })
    .then(user => {
        if (!user) {
            console.log("This email is not associated with a registered account");
            
            // send error message to the client
            return res.status(404).json("This email is not associated with a registered account");
        }
        
        console.log("This email exists in the database. Proceeding...")
    })
    .catch(err => {
        return res.status(500).json(err.message);
    });

    const token = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString("hex");
    const myDate = new Date();
    const newDate = new Date(myDate);

    // if the email exists, run this update to the account with the associated email
    User.updateOne({ email: "ralph@gmail.com" }, {
        $set: {
            resetPasswordToken: token,
            resetPasswordExpires: newDate.setHours(newDate.getHours() + 1)
        }
    })
    .then(updates => console.log(updates))
    .catch(err => {
        return res.status(500).json(err.message);
    });
});
```

Here we are querying to find the document where the email is ralph@gmail.com, and the using the $set operator to update the associated values of resetPasswordToken and resetPasswordExpires to their new respective values.

Comment: ok but I already do a User.findOne above to see if there's a user with this mail and if so, return an error message
so i remove this ?

Comment: No you don't need to remove it. You said your problem was the user.update wasn't executed, so I was addressing that issue. Replace user.update(...) in your code snippet with my answer

Comment: I tried with your solution but it doesn’t want to work. But that’s weird because I have an update in my server which works 

Comment: I edited my answer, while refactoring your code and making a few small additions. Take a look